# reading csv file from a local directory

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to read a CSV file from a local directory and I kept getting the error. I use the same code to read the same CSV file that I hosted on the public server. I use the URL to point to the CSV file and it work fine. I am not sure why I am getting this error when I try to read the file that is stored on a local directory.

```html
export class CsvreadService {

    url ="assets/cases.csv";
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getInfo(){
      return this.http.get(this.url, {responseType:'text'})
  }

}




@Component({
  selector: 'csvread-app',
  templateUrl: './csvread.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./csvread.component.css'],
  moduleId:module.id
})
export class  CsvreadComponent implements OnInit{

    public userArray: Covid[] = [];

    constructor(private csvreader:CsvreadService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData()

    }

    getData(){
        this.csvreader.getInfo().subscribe(data=>
            {
                let csvToRowArray = data.split("\n");
                for (let index = 1; index < csvToRowArray.length - 1; index++) {
                let row = csvToRowArray[index].split(",");
                this.userArray.push(new Covid( row[0], row[1], parseInt(row[2]), row[3],row[4].trim()));
                }
                console.log(this.userArray);
                },
                error => {
                console.log(error);
                }
                );
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting assets path in angular.json file like this -

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
           "assets": ["src/assets", ...], # define your assets path here
            ...
          },
           ...
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: I am on a native script development environment. do I have to update the same file angular.json?

Comment: @user11766958 I haven't worked on native scripts with Angular but yeah give it a try if it works for you!

Comment: This doesn't work for a Nativescript app!